# Fake object with Dynamic properties

Tags: javascript, import, object-literal, object-properties

I am trying to simulate a get request where the speed will change.

```
  export const fakeData = {
      timestamp: 1567606228,
      speed: generatespeed()
    };

    function generatespeed () {
      return Math.floor(Math.random() * 100);
    }
```

To simulate this in the page I simply import it and call it on a setInterval,

```
setInterval(() => {
    this.newData = fakeData;
}, 2000);
```

The speed however is the stays the same, I could just call the function but I would like to make the object properties change. Is this possible?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are invoking the function while setting the value. You can use `get` here.

```
export const fakeData = {
  timestamp: 1567606228,
  get speed(){ 
     return generatespeed()
  }
};

function generatespeed () {
  return Math.floor(Math.random() * 100);
}
```